# How to emit IL for ref locals using ILGenerator?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil

The following C# snippet:

```cs
int x = 10;
ref int y = ref x;
```

is compiled to this IL:

```
.locals init (
    [0] int32 x,
    [1] int32& y
)

ldc.i4.s 10
stloc.0
ldloca.s 0
stloc.1
ret
```

How do I create a local of type `int32&` using `ILGenerator`?

I looked at the `ILGenerator.DeclareLocal()` method, but did not find a suitable overload.

Comment: Just give it the ByRef type created using the above function `MakeByRefType`. ByRef locals aren't a separate IL, it's just a different type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By-reference locals are just locals with different type. To make type by-ref, you should call `.MakeByRefType()`

```cs
        // void Foo()
        var meth = new DynamicMethod("Foo", returnType: typeof(void), parameterTypes: null);
        var il = meth.GetILGenerator();

        // int x;
        var xLocal = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
        // ref int y;
        var yLocal = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int).MakeByRefType());

        // x = 10;
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 10);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, xLocal);

        // ref y = ref x;
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, xLocal);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, yLocal);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var action = meth.CreateDelegate<Action>();
        action(); // ensure no InvalidProgramException
```